# Regular Expressions - Find hexadecimal numbers' matches excluding the 0 of the next hexadecimal number

Tags: java, regex

Goal - I need to retrieve all hexadecimal numbers from my input String.

Example inputs and matches --

1- Input = "0x480x8600x89dfh0x89BABCE" (The "" are not included in the input).
should produce following matches:

- 0x48 ( as opposed to 0x480)
- 0x860
- 0x89df
- 0x89BABCE

I have tried this Pattern:

```
"0[xX][\\da-fA-F]+"
```

But it results in the following matches:

- 0x480
- 0x89df
- 0x89BABCE

2- Input = "0x0x8600x89dfh0x89BABCE" (The "" are not included in the input).

Should produce following matches:

- 0x860
- 0x89df
- 0x89BABCE

Is such a regex possible?

I know that I can first split my input using the String.split("0[xX]"), and then for each String I can write logic to retrieve the first valid match, if there is one.

But I want to know if I can achieve the desired result using just a Pattern and a Matcher.

Here's my current code.

```
package toBeDeleted;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "0[xX][\\da-fA-F]+";
        String input = "0x480x860x89dfh0x89BABCE";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Starting at : " + m.start()
                    + ", Ending at : " + m.end()
                    + ", element matched : " + m.group());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check that the next character is not an "x"

```
String pattern = "0[xX]([1-9a-fA-F]|0(?![xX]))+";
```

Doesn't provide a match as 0x0 for the second example, though.  However, you did state that matches should exclude the "0" preceding the next hex number, so not really sure why that would be matched.

Comment: Yes you are right. Cases 1 and 2 are mutually exclusive cause if we are giving priority to previous matches, the first case should produce 0x480 like "0[xX][\\da-fA-F]+" would. I will update the question with a remark. And thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.
>   -- Jamie Zawinski

If you just use `.split("0x")`, and tack 0x back on each (non-empty) result, you'll be done.

Comment: I know what you're saying. But I need to only know if such a regular expression is possible. To know what is possible is not the same as to achieve a result using the best option. If I had to code this, I would use a split method too. But my interviewer was interested in knowing if I knew if a regex could solve this.